# K means cluster analysis result using R

Tags: r, k-means

I tried a k means cluster analysis on a data set. The data set for customers includes the order number (the number of time that a customer has placed an order with the company;can be any number) ,order day (the day of the week the most recent order was placed; 0 to 6) and order hour (the hour of the day the most recent order was placed; 0 to 23) for loyal customers. I scaled the values and used.

```
# K-Means Cluster Analysis
fit <- kmeans(mydata, 3) # 5 cluster solution
# get cluster means 
aggregate(mydata,by=list(fit$cluster),FUN=mean)
```

However, I am getting a few negative values as well. On the internet they say that this means the differences within  group are greater than with that for other groups. However, I cannot understand how to interpret the output.
Can you please give an example of how to interpret?

```
Group.1  order_number      order_dow order_hour_of_day
1       1 -0.4434400796  0.80263819338    -0.04766613741
2       2  1.6759259419  0.09051366962     0.07815242904
3       3 -0.3936748015 -1.00553744774     0.01377787416
```

Comment: A reproducible example with some data would help. Is difficult to interprest result without knowing how your data is looking like. But maybe someone can help anyway...

Comment: Data looks like order number=27,32,4 ..., order day of week=2 (Tuesday),4 (Thursday),0 (sunday),....order hour of day=7(7 a.m),14 (2p.m) ...for each row.